# PDF javascript to highlight expired date

Tags: javascript, pdf

Here I have code for java pdf to change text color if the date is expired. However, the code I entered is turning current date to red. help resolve.

```
var DT = new Date();
var EXP = this.getField("Ratings1").value;
var EXD = util.scand("dd-mmm-yyyy", EXP);
if (DT.valueOf() > EXD.valueOf())
{
event.target.textColor = color.red;
}
else
{
event.target.textColor = color.black;
}
this.calculateNow();
```

Comment: You seem to be using JavaScript for Acrobat? Is this correct?

Comment: Maybe this article can help https://acrobatusers.com/tutorials/date_time_part1/